# Change Value of Variable in Function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-parameter

The final values for `x` and `y` should be `x = 4` and `y = 21`. I understand why `y = 21`, but why is `x = 4`? Should "a = 5" not change the value to 5? Thanks

```
int f(int a, int *b){
    a = 5;
    *b = *b + 3*a;
}

int main(){
    int x, y;
    x = 4;
    y = 6;
    f(x, &y);
    // What are x and y now?
}
```

Comment: C uses pass by value for all function arguments. Changing a variable within a function does not change the value of the original variable that was passed in.

Comment: @kaylum Would you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: Best if you consult your text book. This fundamental of C language is covered in any basic C book or tutorial.

Comment: Passing by Value means that the function gets a copy of the arguments, so any changes made inside the function are not reflected in the original variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function a is passed by value not by reference, so the x value will no tb e changed. While b is passed by reference, so value of y is changed.